# Unity C#/Blender Model not rotating correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, blender

So I created a turrent model in blender an imported into unity everything was looking good I got a little rotation script put togeather for my hub scene and rotation works good

Now moving into the code trying to rotate the barrel to look torwards the enemy doesnt look so good

Heres a short gameplay video to demonstrate the issue

[Demonstration](http://kot90.altervista.org/survius/display.php?name=UZ1FlLTz9I)

the barrel of the turrent is facing a completly different place then the enemy I would much prefer to fix the issue in code rather then rebuilding the model from scratch so heres what Im doing currently(thats not working)

```c#
private void Update(){
        FlameForgedTime.UpdateTime ();

        if (isInGame) {
            RegenerateHitpoint ();
            //Look for enemy
            if (FlameForgedTime.Time - lastAttack > StatsHelper.Instance.GetStatValue (Stat.Speed)) {
                Collider[] col = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position,StatsHelper.Instance.GetStatValue (Stat.Range),LayerMask.GetMask("Enemy"));
                if (col.Length != 0) {
                    //find closest enemy
                    int closestIndex = 0;
                    float dist = Vector3.SqrMagnitude (col [closestIndex].transform.position - transform.position);
                    for (int i = 1; i < col.Length; i++) {
                        float newDistance = Vector3.SqrMagnitude (col [i].transform.position - transform.position);
                        if (newDistance < dist) {
                            dist = newDistance;
                            closestIndex = i;
                        }
                    }
                    //shoot enemy
//Rotate turrent to look at enemy                   GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.LookAt(col[closestIndex].transform);
                    ShootEnemy(col[closestIndex].transform);
                    lastAttack = Time.time;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So on my turrent(parent gameobject) i have the tag "Player" as the turrent is loaded in a preloader scene and is not accessible by a public GameObject field

For some reason the Y is the axis the turrent rotates on

Anyways I get the closest enemy to the tower and then do a LookAt to try to get the turret to look at the enemy and then shoot at the enemy however that is not working correctly as you can see by the video

Comment: *Heres a short gameplay video to demonstrate the issue"* Where is the video?

Comment: theres a link that says "Demonstration" thats the video

Comment: Link wasn't working when I clicked it. It's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "forward" axis on your model (that is, the direction the gun barrels point) doesn't line up with what Unity says is the forward axis.

"Forward" in Unity is along the positive Z direction, so your model doesn't line up with its transform's local forward (which is what points towards things when using `LookAt()`).  Looks like your model is aligned with forward along the positive X axis instead.

There are three ways to fix this:

1. rotate it in Blender and reexport (best option)
2. create an empty parent GameObject that "becomes" the gun object (that is, all references point to this new object, any scripts move from where they are now to here, etc), but you put the current object inside and rotate the now-child transform by 90 degrees.  This is also called "recentering" sometimes.  With assets that aren't yours, this is sometimes the only option.
3. script-wise rotate by 90 degrees after performing a `LookAt()` (not recommended)

Comment: by rotate in blender do you mean i need to just do a 90 degree rotate? or will i need to rebuild it from scratch?

Comment: @FlamingGenius Just rotate it 90 degrees in Blender and save it.